# Alternative Format Options

Tags: discussion, feature-request, formatting

At first: the possibilities to format a question or answer is fine. I like the markdown style, also the buttons to use it via click.

But we use not only clients, there have all keys for format a post. Especially is this a problem to add code, inline and also blocks. The default for the formatting of source is the `` ` `` string and enough spaces before each line of a code block. But the problem is, that it not possible to use on different clients, like a tablet or smartphone. The usability of alternative clients, like smartphone and tablets, is more and more given. Perhaps it is possible to add a other chance to add code, specially source block. A small idea is a popup to insert source, copy/paste, and send the content of this popup to the textarea of question/answer. So that it possible, that the source give automatically the spaces before all lines. The current noun on the alternative clients have the options to select parts, but not easy and not about many lines. This is problem on the size and the scrolling and also the problem to go back to the button to textarea.

- yes, the alternatives client is not the important focus for WPSE, especially on source topics, but it becomes more and more and WPSE should have no restriction.

*now thanks for the correction of my english*

Comment: I've never used it on any non-desktop device, so I've to ask: Is there no WYSIWYG editor? Because that one has a code-formatting button.

Comment: The question/answer fields have a quicktag for format as code, but this works only with selected lines. The selecting on a mobile device is not really easy inside a textarea.

Comment: All my devices are from that Fruit Company, so in the iTablet is relatively easy to format (especially with the [SwipeSelection](http://www.ijailbreak.com/cydia/swipeselection-cydia-tweak-ios/) tool). But I use the iMobile as a read-only device, ¿are you really writing code with your phone? Bloody wizards!

Comment: Not often, but the same problem on copy/paste to format the code block. I think is not a problem from all users, yes. But i think, that WPSE should not a restriction for devices and the enhancement of the WYSIWYG editor is a small enhancement with great return for the users.